# How to fix the width of columns in tabularx table?

Tags: tables, tabularx, cell, column-width

I am working on `Springer` template, I want to create a `tabularx` `table` and I to fix the width of the columns. I work on `landscape` page and I want create a table like that table which contains 34 columns:

[image]

But the problem is that, I can't fix the width of tables, the results of my table :

[image]

and that's my code:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}          % twocolumn

\begin{landscape}



\start{document}
\begin{table} [htp]

\setcellgapes{3pt}
\centering
\scriptsize
\makegapedcells
%0.0255
%0.0745
%0.0145

\begin{tabularx} {\linewidth}{| p{0.072\textwidth}|
                                 *{32}{p{0.011\textwidth}|}
                                p{0.069\textwidth}|}  



\hline  
A & \multicolumn{18}  {m{0.198\textwidth}|}   {A} 
  & \multicolumn{9}  {m{0.099\textwidth}|}   {A}
  & \multicolumn{5}  {m{0.055\textwidth}|}   {A}
  &Ref

\\
\hline
A & 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25&26&27&28&29&30&31&32&Ref

\\
\hline

\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{landscape}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Why are you specifying a specific width when you're working with `multicolumn` anyways?

Comment: `tabularx` needs al teasl one `X` type column to work properly. If you just use `p` type columns, there is no reason to use `tabularx`.

Comment: Please add some more information on the desired output. Do you need linebreaks inside of table cells? If so, `p` type columns can be a good choice. If not, you could also ge for `w` type columns (from the `array` package). Are the numbers in your table the actual entries or will you replace them later? With what kind of contents will they be replaced with? Will you add more rows? What will their contents look like? Do you need linebreaks inside of the `\multicolumn` cells or just a single line? How will the contents of the "Ref"  column look like? Author year citations or numeric ones?...

Comment: Please make your code compilable. Several packages such as `makecell` and `tabularx`are clearly missing. `\start{document}` should be replaced with `\begin{document}`. Also, you can't use `\begin{landscape}` before `\begin{document}`. Please fix that.

Comment: why are you using tabularx??? as the only point of that is to vary the column width automatically, just use a normal tabular.

Answer (score 1):

You may use tabular*, set the tabcolsep to 0pt, and let tabular* calculate the width by using `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}`. If you need multi line cells, just change `wc{0.025\linewidth}` to `p{0.025\linewidth}`, and similar for other other length.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}          % twocolumn

\usepackage{array, pdflscape}


\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table*} [!htp]

\footnotesize
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

\begin{tabular*} {\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}| wc{0.03\textwidth}|
                                 *{32}{wc{0.025\textwidth}|}
                                wc{0.069\textwidth}|}  



\hline  
A & \multicolumn{18}  {c|}   {A} 
  & \multicolumn{9}  {c|}   {A}
  & \multicolumn{5}  {c|}   {A}
  &Ref

\\
\hline
A & 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25&26&27&28&29&30&31&32&Ref

\\
\hline

\end{tabular*}
\end{table*}

\end{landscape}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I will appreciate if the downvoter could justify the down vote. Difficult to see what is wrong with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need at least *one* `X` column:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}          % twocolumn
\usepackage{tabularx,pdflscape}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\small\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|*{32}{p{0.011\textwidth}|}X|}  \hline  
A & \multicolumn{18}  {m{0.198\textwidth}|}   {A} 
  & \multicolumn{9}  {m{0.099\textwidth}|}   {A}
  & \multicolumn{5}  {m{0.055\textwidth}|}   {A}
  &Ref\\\hline
A & 
1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15&16&17&18&19&20&21&22&23&24&25&26&27&28&29&30&31&32&Ref\\\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The code did not run please check it again

Comment: ?? My image is the output of the `pdflatex`run ...